# Compile error: Variable does not exist

Tags: apex, trigger

I was trying to implement a lead trigger where upon conversion and adding the optional opportunity, it will  change the contact custom picklist field (`Lead_Status__c`) to `"Qualified"` (after the conversion).

I have the code below but am getting an error:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: `oppToContact` at line 20 column 21

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (after update)
{
    if (Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            Set<Id> setContact = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> setOpp = new Set<Id>();
            //Map<ID,ID> oppToContact = new Map<ID,ID>();

            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new)
            {

                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunity and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if ( ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null)
                {  

                    setContact.add(ld.ConvertedContactId );

                    setOpp.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId );

                    oppToContact.put(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId,ld.ConvertedContactID); // Error Line 

                }

            }

            if(setContact.size() > 0 )
            {

                List<Contact> lstContact = [select id , Lead_Status__c from contact where id in:setContact];

                for(Contact cont : lstContact)
                {
                    cont.Lead_Status__c ='Qualified';
                }

                update lstContact ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

after editing the code like below, I'm now getting a different error: **Error   Error: Compile Error: map must have exactly 2 type arguments at line 6 column 9**

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (after update)
```

{
    if (Trigger.isAfter)
    { if (Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
        Set setContact = new Set();
         Set setOpp = new  Set();
        Map oppToContact = new  Map();
        for (Lead ld : Trigger.new)
        {
               // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if ( ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null)
            {
            setContact.add(ld.ConvertedContactId );
            setOpp.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId );
            oppToContact.put(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId,ld.ConvertedContactID); 
            }
            }
        if(setContact.size() > 0 )
            {
        List lstContact = [select id,Lead_Status__c from contact where id in:setContact];
        for(Contact cont : lstContact)
        {
            cont.Lead_Status__c ='Qualified';
        }
        update lstContact ;
       }
        }
    }
}

Thanks for the answers, you guys are awesome

Answer (score 2):

Whats the type of your set Set setContact = new Set(); syntax should be like below

For String the syntax is like this : Set s1 = new Set();

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) {
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Set<Id> setContact = new Set<Id>();
            Set<Id> setOpp = new  Set<Id>();
            Map<Id,String> oppToContact = new  Map<Id,String>();
            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if ( ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null) {
                    setContact.add(ld.ConvertedContactId );
                    setOpp.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId );
                    oppToContact.put(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId,ld.ConvertedContactID); 
                }
            }
            if(setContact.size() > 0 ) {
                List<contact> lstContact = [select id,Lead_Status__c from contact where id in:setContact];
                for(Contact cont : lstContact) {
                    cont.Lead_Status__c ='Qualified';
                }
                update lstContact ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code stays

Comment: Hi RedDevil, Following your code, I get a different compiler error: Error Error: Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'setContact' at line 6 column 20
   Set setContact = new Set();  
Please advise

Comment: As i explained mention the type of set  Set<Id> setContact = new Set<Id>(); This is just illustration please mention based on your scenario

Comment: it supposed to be a String since it will find the unique Id of the Contact and the Opp

Comment: then it will  be Set<String> setContact = new Set<String>();

Answer (score 0):

Hello Raelis Silvestre,
   Check your code on line:20, method/variable name is **ConvertedContactId** not **ConvertedContactID**.

```
Trigger Lead on Lead (after update) {
    if (Trigger.isAfter) { 
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            Set<String> setContact = new Set<String>();
            Set<String> setOpp = new  Set<String>();
            Map<String,String> oppToContact = new  Map<String,String>();
            for (Lead ld : Trigger.new) {
                // Find all converted Leads with Opportunitiy and add ConvertedOpportunityId to setConvertedOppIds
                if ( ld.isConverted && ld.ConvertedOpportunityId != null && ld.ConvertedContactId != null) {
                    setContact.add(ld.ConvertedContactId );
                    setOpp.add(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId );
                    oppToContact.put(ld.ConvertedOpportunityId,ld.ConvertedContactId); 
                }
            }
            if(setContact.size() > 0 ) {
                List<Contact> lstContact = [select id,Lead_Status__c from Contact where id = :setContact];
                for(Contact cont : lstContact) {
                    cont.Lead_Status__c ='Qualified';
                }
                update lstContact ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Regards,
Alap Mistry